# Dynamically loading Dictionary KVPs into Anonymous types

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda, anonymous-types

I want to load all the `KeyValuePairs` in a `Dictionary<string, string>` into anonymous types during runtime. There will be no knowledge ahead of time of the contents of the Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> callParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();

logger.WithParams(() => new { Val1= val1, Val2= val2, Val3= val3 });
```

How can I add the KVPs of `callParams` to the set of anonymous types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean - but if you're trying to get the *property names* to depend on the keys in the dictionary, you're out of luck: anonymous types are created for you by the compiler at compile-time, with the property names that you specify. If you don't know the keys until execution time, you can't have the anonymous types...

If you're using .NET 4 you could potentially use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) and dynamic typing... but what's the bigger picture here? Why can't you just pass the dictionary around as it is?